# cant 'cordova emulate ios' from terminal

Tags: ios, cordova

I updated Xcode. Not sure if that's the problem but it is where the problem started.
But long story short:

-"`$ cordova emulate android`" works

-"`$ cordova emulate ios`" does not work

It gives me (this is the last part of the output):

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

2014-10-03 16:35:53.054 ios-sim[74808:507] stderrPath: /Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-10-03 16:35:53.055 ios-sim[74808:507] stdoutPath: /Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-10-03 16:35:53.085 ios-sim[74808:507] -[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea40503090
2014-10-03 16:35:53.086 ios-sim[74808:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea40503090'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98e1025c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8cc4ee75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98e1312d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98d6e272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98d6ddf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim                             0x00000001014b8e29 -[iPhoneSimulator LoadSimulatorFramework:] + 245
    6   ios-sim                             0x00000001014ba8e0 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 2271
    7   ios-sim                             0x00000001014bacb2 main + 101
    8   ios-sim                             0x00000001014b8ce4 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
/Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/cordova/run: line 158: 74808 Abort trap: 6           ios-sim launch "$SIMULATOR_APP_PATH" --stderr "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" --stdout "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" $TARGET_FLAG --exit
Error: /Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 134
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

However, I can run the simulator fine from Xcode itself.

I have no clue what to do, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update ios-sim?

Comment: thanks! you are my one day hero. 'sudo npm install ios-sim -g' worked for me. Not sure if it's the proper way. If you drop that as an answer i will boost your rep.

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 6 you'll need version 3 of ios-sim. Check your version by running `ios-sim --version`. Upgrade by running `sudo npm update ios-sim -g`.